# How to Debug GNOME Hangs?

Tags: 14.04, gnome

In the last day, my system running 14.04 has started to hang for ~10 seconds after seemingly common actions: editing a URL in chrome, changing to a different workspace, etc.  The "perpetrators" seem to be high memory consumers: Chrome and Intellij IDEA - but the hangs occur even when memory usage is relatively low (~30%), but only when one of these programs is open.

The symptoms are:

- I change workspaces or click on some interactive element
- Hang starts, can move mouse, but cannot interact with anything
- Stare angrily at my computer for the next ten seconds
- Hang ends, resume work

The GNOME logs only mention one seemingly [benign problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/at-spi2-core/+bug/1228567).

This is starting to drive me crazy, though.  Continually being unable to type that thing you just figured out after switching workspaces is one of the more frustrating experiences I've had in... Too long...

So, any ideas on debug strategies for this problem?